# Can I get some examples with this issue?

Tags: aiml

I'm seeming to have a little trouble with the <srai> tag. Can I have some other examples of to use it better please?

Comment: The SRAI tag can be used in many ways. Could you give some more information on the trouble you are having with it?

Comment: Ok, so I'm tryna get my ai to know that certain slang is related to one word, how ik srai (or Sr) works is once you put the original in the coats, it knows that what ever the user says, it means that, for example: "I know" is the original but many ppl will say ik or I Kno and I'd wanna put that in a srai instead of writing code all over again for it, how do I achieve this with srai coats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to create your main category. In this case, the bot will respond to "I know"

```
<category>
    <pattern>I KNOW</pattern>
    <template>Great. Glad you understand it.</template>
</category>
```

Now you can create other ways of saying "I know", like "ik" or "I kno" and use <srai> to activate your main category

```
<category>
    <pattern>IK</pattern>
    <template><srai>I know</srai></template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>I KNO</pattern>
    <template><srai>I know</srai></template>
</category>
```

This will allow the following conversation:

**Human:** ik
**Bot:** Great. Glad you understand it.

Comment: Ohh thanks much! Really helpful and straight to the point cuz I think what I did was added the <srai> above the template  oops